# start searching in a 2 dimensional array from a sertent element java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code that searches through a 2 dimensional array and tries to find the closest element to "x" that is empty, if "x" has any data in. The elements' coordinates are given from another method. For example "x" is (3,2). If there's no empty element then the code must continue searching in the whole array.

```
public void find(int row, int column) {
    for (int i = row - 1; i < row + 2; i++) {
        for (int k = column - 1; k < column + 2; k++) {

            if (this.arr[i][k].equals(" ")) {
                System.out.println(i + "," + k + " is empty.");
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am looking foreword for any helpful suggestions on how to code this method.
Thank you.

Comment: And what exaclty is your problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want it to search, after that, the cell that is in diagonal top-left to **1** (if there existed any), then the one on top of 1, and keep doing this "round search" until you find the element or you look in all the array, right?

Comment: @911DidBush    I can not find a way that after the above code finishes and no empty element is found, then i what it to search the rest of the array.

Comment: @dquijada      Yes. If no empty element is found from the code above, then it has to start from above the element of "1" (in the case i mentioned in my question, but keep in mind that the start point may be any element of the array ) and search around like a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under assumptions

- this is matrix (each row has equal num of columns)
- method arguments are valid: `0 <= row < numOfRows` and `0 <= column < numOfColumns`

this code will do search of 2 dimensional array around specified element in the way you've described. 
Note that this is not clock direction round search around specified element, but search from top left corner to bottom right corner (from top to bottom and from left to right)

```
public void find(int row, int column) {
        int distance = 1;
        int numOfRows = arr.length;
        int numOfColumns = 0;
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            numOfColumns = arr[0].length;
        }
        int maxDistance = Math.max(numOfRows, numOfColumns);        
        for (distance = 1; distance < maxDistance; distance ++) {
            for (int i = Math.max(row - distance, 0); i <= Math.min(row + distance, numOfRows - 1); i++) {
                if (Math.abs(i - row) == distance) {
                    // Check row
                    for (int k = Math.max(column - distance, 0); k <= Math.min(column + distance, numOfColumns - 1); k++) {
                        if (arr[i][k] == null || arr[i][k].trim().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is empty.");
                            return;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is not empty.");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Check only edge elements
                    int k = column - distance;
                    if (k >= 0) {
                        if (arr[i][k] == null || arr[i][k].trim().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is empty.");
                            return;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is not empty.");
                        }
                    }
                    k = column + distance;
                    if (k < numOfColumns) {
                        if (arr[i][k] == null || arr[i][k].trim().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is empty.");
                            return;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println((i+1) + "," + (k+1) + " is not empty.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No empty elements");
    }
```

Comment: Your code plus some modifications i made works like a charm. Thank you. By the way, could you explain me how dose this work?
I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are three loops. Consider the 1st one as radius, with each iteration next circle (frame) of elements around specified position is processed. First inner loop iterates rows inside the frame from top to bottom. Last loop iterates columns, but only for uppermost and lowermost rows inside the frame. For inner rows only leftmost and rightmost elements are processed since elements in between have been processed earlier